# EF Core - Issue with including list of child property which have their own list of child properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble figuring out how to include a list of child property which can have its own list of child property.

My entity is setup as below:

```
public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        //other properties

        public Guid? ParentCommentId { get; set; }

        public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Post CommentForPost { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

I have below relationships:

- One-to-many relationship between `Post` -> `Comment`
- One-to-many relationship between `User` -> `Comment`
- One-to-many relationship between `Comment` -> `Comment`

What I want to do is when I query the comments for a post, include the parent level comment, and all of the parent's child comments (i.e. the `ICollection of ChildComments` property).

Currently I have below LINQ statement setup:

```
return _context.Comments.Include(comment => comment.CreatedBy)
                        .Include(comment => comment.ChildComments)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.CreatedBy)
                        .Where(comment => comment.PostId == postId)
                        .OrderBy(comment => comment.Created)
                        .AsNoTracking();
```

The problem is that I am also getting duplicates. For example, if I test above with below data:

```
Comment1 {
  Id = 1
  ChildComments = Comment2
}
Comment2 {
  Id = 2
  ParentCommentId = 1
  ChildComments = Comment3
}
Comment3 {
  Id = 3
  ParentCommentId = 2
  ChildComments = null
}
Comment4 {
  Id = 4
  ChildComments = null
}
```

If I use above query, I end up getting below. What I want to get back is just a list of parent level comments, and all their child comments (and if the child comments have their own child comments, include them as well).

**Incorrect:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",       
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "childComments": [
            {
                "id": "2",                
                "parentCommentId": "1",
                "childComments": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",                        
                        "parentCommentId": "2",
                        "childComments": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",       
        "parentCommentId": "1",
        "childComments": [
            {
                "id": "3",               
                "parentCommentId": "2",
                "childComments": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",       
        "parentCommentId": "2",
        "childComments": []
    },
    {
        "id": "4",       
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "childComments": []
    }
]
```

---

### What I want to get back:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",       
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "childComments": [
            {
                "id": "2",                
                "parentCommentId": "1",
                "childComments": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",                        
                        "parentCommentId": "2",
                        "childComments": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",       
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "childComments": []
    }
]
```

---

**Update:** I have tried adding in a where clause for `ParentCommentId == null`so the modified query as:

```
return _context.Comments.Include(comment => comment.CreatedBy)
                                    .Include(comment => comment.ChildComments)
                                    .ThenInclude(x => x.CreatedBy)
                                    .Where(comment => comment.PostId == postId)
                                    .Where(comment => comment.ParentCommentId == null)
                                    .OrderBy(comment => comment.Created)
                                    .AsNoTracking();
```

But the issue is that with above linq statement, I am not getting children of children. I.e. with my example above, I am getting below instead of the correct answer.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",       
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "childComments": [
            {
                "id": "2",                
                "parentCommentId": "1",
                "childComments": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",       
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "childComments": []
    }
]
```

Comment: You probably need a where on the main query to get comments that says .Where(x => x.ParentCommentId == null) or 0 or whatever the value is of the parent comment. Then only get it's children, so that you don't get the children appearing as their own main comment trees.

Comment: @topher I tried that. Unfortunately the problem is that it only includes the immediate children. I.e. in my example above, I won't get "Comment 3". I will get Comment1 and Comment2 (as 2 is an immediate child of 1) but 3 is not returned.

Comment: I would consider you use the postId in your Where and get all items in a flat list. Then you can create a bit of logic to recreate the tree. Works much faster because it is one call to DB and rest is in memory.